# import swift framework in objc project xcode 11.3.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have question about framework.
When I import my customized swift framework in Objc project, I cant init class object and find customized delegate.
And I also have script to combined different framework like this: 
Is my script problem?
Or project setting problem?

Xcode 11.3.1
swift 5

```
#!/bin/sh
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "XXXSDK" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "XXXSDK" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/XXXSDK.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
# Step 3. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/XXXSDK.framework/Modules/XXXSDK.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/XXXSDK.framework/Modules/XXXSDK.swiftmodule"
fi
# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/XXXSDK.framework/XXXSDK" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/XXXSDK.framework/XXXSDK" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/XXXSDK.framework/XXXSDK"
# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/XXXSDK.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/XXXSDK.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../XXXSDKDemo"
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/XXXSDK.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../XXXSDKObjcDemo"
# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

[image]

Comment: May be class and delegate isn't compatible with objc?

Answer (score 0):

If you build your framework with xcframeworks, all this configuration mess will be a lot easier. If you can, give it a try. Look at https://github.com/bielikb/xcframeworks

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem to consume swift framework in objective c, check if the framework has the correct **.h** file in it.

If you want to combine multiple framework in one the you can use **lipo** command from terminal. Please do check the combined framework after lipo and see if there is the header file.

Also try to use the frameworks individually before lipo.